# Laravel Debugger showing duplicated queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent, phpdebugbar

[image]

Does any one has an idea about this. I don't know why it is showing duplicated queries. I searched a lot, found one answer on stackoverflow, but didn't get proper answer. If anyone faced the same error then please let me know. Thank you

```
protected $_param;
public function __construct(Utility $utility)
{
    $league = $utility->checkDomainController();
    view()->share('league', $league);

    $this->league = $league;
}
```

This is the code in controller. which shares league to all the views. But there is only one query in **$league = $utility->checkDomainController();**

> Here is the checkDomainController

```
if(\Request::server('HTTP_HOST') == env('MAIN_DOMAIN'))
    {
        $leagueSlug = Route::current()->getParameter('league');
        $league = League::where('url', $leagueSlug)->first();
    }
    else
    {
        $league = League::where('custom_domain', \Request::server('HTTP_HOST'))->first();
    }
    if(!$league)
    {
      //error page
    }

    return $league;
```

Comment: Show related code please

Comment: Turn on your mysql general log and watch the queries being run, you may actually be running duplicate queries.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin updated. Please check it

Comment: @user3158900 how may I do it? And where should I check it. Thank you

Comment: It's N+1 problem, i think, you must eager load languages with the selected element

Comment: Hi @Maraboc thank you for your reply, Let me explain you what I want. What I'm doing is I'm checking for the league SLUG from $utility->checkDomainController();, now if I found any league, I want to share it on all views, and if not then I want to show 404 Page.

Comment: can you show us the content of `checkDomainController`? to help us detect the problem :)

Comment: @Maraboc okay please check it, I've edited the code

Comment: @Maraboc, I guess, the count of that duplicate query is equal to the number of Views shown there in the Debugbar

Comment: And how many times did your controller be called? because each time it will execute the same query !

Comment: @Maraboc just once in constructor, and I'm sharing it on all views.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you call a property which relies on a related model in blade, Laravel executes a new query, unless you eager load and pass from the controller to the view the preloaded data.

This example you posted seems to me as a loop somewhere within your blade code. Maybe if you can share a bit more of the code related to the front-end, I can help you figure it out.